# limit client certificate to domain name

Tags: authentication, certificates, client-side, client

If i want to use client certificates for authentication to a certain part of my website, is it possible to make the client certificate only work on a certain domain name?

I know when requesting the client certificate you can request the CA.
But i want it so if my site is domain.com and the client visits a fake website domainn.com then when the client certificate is requested on that fake website it will be impossible for the real client certificate to be used as it wont match to the correct domain.

Comment: What's your concern with cert reuse?

Comment: Would fake website domainn.com be any less convincing if it does not retrieves the client certificate?

Answer (score 2):

You can't regulate where the cert goes as it's handled by the client (browser in your case). There's nothing in a client cert to restrict it to specific domains. The browser is free to send it wherever it wishes. There are settings in the browser that lets users control where the certs go, but that too is out of your control.

That said, I'm not sure why you care who gets the cert. If you're using client certs, there's no chance of phishing or MiTMing.

Comment: do you know of any documents that go into detail of how phishing is not possible?

Comment: Phishing attacks credentials - passwords and sometimes OTPs (eg: Google Authenticator). When you're using client certs, you generally don't have passwords. If you're using passwords with client certs as a 2FA, then phishing would be possible, though the user would likely get a browser popup asking them to select the cert for the website. And they still wouldn't get the cert's private key as that is never transmitted. So it is safe against all but browser vulnerabilities and malware installed on the computer.

Comment: What are you concerned that will be phished?

Comment: Phishing is always "possible", it's a user issue: as long as a user is **willing** to enter data in a form in a random website, and **able** to connect to that website (not possible if you're on an intranet with only access to a few white listed legit domains), and **able** to remember that secret code (not possible if you don't remember the code and have a browser autofill feature that only works on a given domain), phishing is possible.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not sure how phishing is possible if mutual auth SSL is the only authentication in use,. What would be phisbed? The private key? Seems unlikely to me.

Comment: my idea was to have our server request a certificate. user use their client one.  then the server would get it, encrypt something and send it back that which can only then be viewed/verified by the client certificate. thats the basics of it.  i am going to try some testing to see if i can do a kind of phising attack.. so a fake website will request the certificate and then when received it will then access the REAL site and send on the requst it got itself.

Comment: @PixelPaul - what you are describing is [TLS mutual authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). It will be built into your web/app server, all web browsers, and other HTTPS clients. No need for you to play around with encrypting things yourself. TLS mutual authentication is a very solid standard that has been around for years and has great implementations. You won't do better writing your own.

Comment: @PixelPaul - You still haven't specified what you are concerned will be phished. The private key? Something else?

Comment: i want to prevent a user from being phished. at the moment we can only rely on the user checking the domain name and SSL, but this is not reliable as the user can miss those easy.

Comment: @PixelPaul - are you going to be using both client certs and username/passwords? If that is the case, then the user getting phished isn't a big deal as the attacker still can't login without the client cert and it's private key.

Comment: @PixelPaul - If this is a website requiring super-high security (eg: a bank), then you can require [U2F](https://fidoalliance.org/specifications/overview/). That is pretty much unphishable (tho so too is a client cert!). Otherwise I think you may be overthinking this.